# Victus and Wrex have disappeared

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just finished the turian platoon mission on Tuchanka, and then the bomb mission.
Then, I did the prothean DLC mission.

Now, when I return to the war room, Wrex and General Victus are no longer there...and I even talked to both of them right after the tuchanka bomb mission.

Are they supposed to disappear at this point, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Tis a bug. Wrex and Victus will not leave the ship till the genophage mission has been completed. Looks like you'll have to load a earlier save, unfortunately. Hope you're the paranoid sort who saves often!

Answer (score 1):

I completed the meeting and normally would enter the War Room to speak with Wrex & Victus separately to get their mission requests (Note, they all now active in the Galaxy Map). However I diverted to the Prothean DLC first and upon my return to Normandy they have Vanished as well. I went to speak with Eve in Med BAY and Wrex enters to engage with Mordin as usual. Back to War Room, still gone. Did the Grunt Scout Recovery, spoke to Wrex in War Room, he leaves and I can now talk to Victus.

So, NOT immediately entering the War Room seems to trigger the Bug , bot for me is was minor, missing some Side Dialog but back on track

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably centuries old inquiry, but I just encountered this problem and what i did was this:

I had a save of the moment AFTER the Eden Prime mission getting Javik, when Victus disappeared. I loaded a save BEFORE the mission and checked that he was still there before the mission. Then I loaded the first mentioned save (the one AFTER the mission), went to check, and he was there once again. Solved.

HOWEVER, this might not be necessary. Maybe you just need to reload the save AFTER the mission is completed (and maybe shut down the game and restart it) and the game will remember he's supposed to be there. I just had an irrational notion that I have to remind the game that he WAS there before by loading an earlier save.

Hope this helps someone, I'm playing it for the first time so I was spooked.